# Media query doesn't work on Chrome for Android

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, media-queries

I have written a media query for tablets with dpi higher than 200.
The tablet it has to work on is the Samsung Galaxy Tab S 10.5. I am trying to use 1 media query to reach iPad retina and the Samsung Tab S, but unfortunately it won't the way I tried.

```
@media screen (device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    body {font-size: 20px; }
    .padding-n { padding: 10px; }
    .button{ color: red; }

    /*table alternate row color for iPad*/
    .white-table > table tr:nth-child(2n) { background: #edf4f7;} 
}
```

This query does work in the standard Android browser, but doesn't work in Chrome for Android.
On iPad it also works fine.

Has anyone a solution for this problem?

Comment: Not sure, but you could try this: @media screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { ... } If you don't use min, it has to be exactly 2 to work. U should also use "and" after screen.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work..
The strange thing is the media query works fine on iPad, also on the default Android browser, but not in FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen it done this way

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

So yours would be:

```
@media (device-pixel-ratio: 2), (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    ...
}
```

OR

```
@media screen and (device-pixel-ratio: 2), screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    ...
}
```

I think the problem with your example is the use of `AND` which means both `(device-pixel-ratio: 2)` and  `(-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)` have to be true. Using a comma turns it into an `OR`.